# Unable to set top/left properties on dynamically generated div through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

Already searched and searched again over the site as well as over the internet and any luck so far.

I have a set of dynamically generated divs through `JQuery` by cloning them from original html source.
While I'm able to set and play with the possitioning properties from the original divs, the cloned ones are not reponding at all (neither to `height` and `width` properties), despite I can select them without issues.

Here is the original `HTML`:

```
<div style="width: 504px; height: 252px; left: 333px; top: 135px;" id="mainHolder">
    <div style="width: 504px; height: 252px;" id="holder">
        <div style="width: 126px; height: 63px;" id="idTile_5369" class="tile"></div>
        <div style="width: 126px; height: 63px;" id="idTile_5373" class="tile"></div>
        <div style="width: 126px; height: 63px;" id="idTile_5377" class="tile"></div>
        <div style="width: 126px; height: 63px;" id="idTile_5381" class="tile"></div>                   
    </div>
    <div id="holderHandler"></div>
</div>
```

Here are the `CSS` rules being applied:

```
#mainHolder{
    position: relative;
}
#holder, #holderHandler, .tile, .tileHandler{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Here the `JS` code:

```
getDataJsonServer('tiles.php', (function(data){ //getDataJsonServer --> custom function to obtain json data from the server through the JQuery getJson method
    var mainHolder=$('#mainHolder');
    var tilesHandler=$('#holder .tile', this.mainHolder).clone();
    tilesHandler.addClass('tileHandler');
    tilesHandler.removeClass('tile');
    tilesHandler.attr('id', function(i, idTileHandler){ return 'idTileHandler_'+extractId(idTileHandler); }); //extractId -->  custom function that extracts the id
    $('#holderHandler', this.mainHolder).append(tilesHandler);

    for(var tile in data){
        $('#idTile_'+data[tile].idTile, this.mainHolder).css({left: data[tile].position.left, top: data[tile].position.top});
        $('#idTileHandler_'+data[tile].idTile, this.mainHolder).css({left: data[tile].positionHandler.left, top: data[tile].positionHandler.top});
    }
}
```

Finally, here the `Json` data retourned by `tiles.php`:

```
"data": [{
    "idTile": 5369,
    "position": {
        "left": -62,
        "top": 0
    },
    "positionHandler": {
        "left": -62,
        "top": 0
    }
},
"idTile": 5373,
    "position": {
        "left": -62,
        "top": 0
    },
    "positionHandler": {
        "left": -62,
        "top": 0
    }
},
"idTile": 5377,
    "position": {
        "left": -62,
        "top": 0
    },
    "positionHandler": {
        "left": -62,
        "top": 0
    }
},
"idTile": 5381,
    "position": {
        "left": -62,
        "top": 0
    },
    "positionHandler": {
        "left": -62,
        "top": 0
    }
}]
```

While the last line inside the `for/in` loop is working perfectly, the other line is simply not setting the `left` and `top` properties, without throwing any error message.

Why is this happennig? is it due to the fact that the second set of divs are dinamically generated as I suspect? How can I solve it?

**Edit:**

- Added the Json object retourned by `tiles.php`
- Changed `this.tilesHandler` by `this.mainHolder` in the `for/in` block (errata).

Comment: you are trying to set an attribute to a function... i think you are wanting to execute the function

Comment: Do you mean to use `.position()`, or is `.position` an object in your `data`?

Comment: data[tile].position is just an object from data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it was a problem on the `extractId()` function, despite I've  tested and re-tested again before posting.

The function was retourning the numeric id portion of the string as it should be, but preceeding it by an underscore character. So, at the end, I was getting the cloned div's with an id with a double underscore.

Sorry for the inconveniences, and thanks for the efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Note Not certain if the `id` of the `clone`'d elements have been changed or not in above piece, yet appears may have been changed, so that not *2* `id`'s with same value in document, after `.clone()` ?

Also, not certain where `data` is defined ? Is `tile` the elements' `DOM` `style` attribute ?

Please clarify what `data` and `tile` variables are. Thanks

Perhaps 1st try quoting `css` properties ?

Try

```
for(var tile in data){
        $('#idTile_'+data[tile].idTile, this.tilesHandler).css({"left": data[tile].position.left, "top": data[tile].position.top});
        $('#idTileHandler_'+data[tile].idTile, this.tilesHandler).css({"left": data[tile].positionHandler.left, "top": data[tile].positionHandler.top});
    }
```

Comment: Id's from the cloned div's have been changed indeed, by using the custom function <code>extractId()</code>. So no duplicated id's are present; this has already being tested and it works properly.

Comment: @user2697714 Is variable `tile` the element's `DOM` `style` property ? Did surrounding `css` properties with "quotes" change those `css` properties ?

Comment: <code>data</code> is just a json object containg the data being retourned by the custom function <code>getDataJsonServer</code>. The data in it is properly arranged as an array of tiles, and that is also working as it should be.
<code>tile</code> is just the index from the <code>for in</code> block.

Comment: surrounding css properties with "quotes" dind't solved the problem, besides the first line within the for works perfectly...

Comment: @user2697714 Not certain what `tile` is ? If possible, can create a jsfiddle ?

Comment: `tile` is just an index for the `for/in` loop, as explained in [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp).

Comment: The `for/in` iterates within the `data` array, inside which each item is a json object containing the positioning parameters (`left` and `top`) for each tile.

Comment: @user2697714 Difficult to accurately assess without all variable included posted ?

Comment: Sorry for that. Added the `json` data set retourned by `tiles.php`. I hope it helps.

Comment: @user2697714 Prior to attempting compose adjusted pieces, should note that there does not appear to be a variable `tile` `in` `data` at `for(var tile in data)`